# CRC Machine in .../.crc/machines/crc/ keeps Growing in Size

Tags: openshift

I am currently using CRC/OpenShift in order to get more familiar with OpenShift and I found that the virtual machine used for CRC keeps growing in size and I am unable to determine the reasons for this.

I am referring to the file in ....crc\machines\crc\crc.vhdx. For a couple of days the size stayed stable but since I started to deploy two test applications this machine keeps growing in size and leads to crc being unresponsive.

I have reviewed the images available and also ssh into the VM to check the different files and file sizes. However, it is still ongoing and I hope someone here experienced it too and can give me the right pointer in order to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue... it is that every time a deployment was created the container image was written to the OpenShift crc VM and therefore, occupying more and more space. I am still figuring out how to avoid that. Should be easy though